# Joining Max Row where Col

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    `shift`.`uid`, 
    `shift`.`activity`, 
    `users`.`fname`, 
    `users`.`lname` 
FROM `shift`, `users` 
WHERE `shift`.`uid` = `users`.`id`
```

It works fine just like that, but I need to add a new column from another table and order by  it.

`times` :

```
| uid | User | time |
+++++++++++++++++++++
|  3  | bob  | 1231 |
|  3  | bob  | 1291 | 
|  4  | ned  | 1651 | 
|  5  | ted  | 5679 | 
|  6  | joe  | 7665 | 
|  6  | joe  | 7864 |
```

How can I include the maximum time from the time table for each user (WHERE `times`.`uid` = `shift`.`uid`) and then order by that column?

Trouble is, all the other tables have one row per user but the time table has multiple and I can't figure out the correct combination of joins and group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join on an aggregate query:

```
SELECT   `shift`.`uid`, 
         `shift`.`activity`, 
         `users`.`fname`, 
         `users`.`lname` ,
         t.max_time
FROM     `shift`
JOIN     `users` ON `shift`.`uid` = `users`.`id`
JOIN     (SELECT   `uid`, MAX(`time`) AS max_time
          FROM     `times`
          GROUP BY `uid`) t ON shift.uid = t.uid
ORDER BY t.max_time
```

Comment: @rolfl indeed, nice catch. Added.

Comment: This one was the most like my original query. Thanks, @Mureinik

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.uid,
       s.activity, 
       u.fname, 
       u.lname,
       MAX(t.time) as maxtime
FROM shift s,
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.uid
INNER JOIN times t ON t.uid = u.id
GROUP BY s.uid,
         s.activity, 
         u.fname, 
         u.lname
ORDER BY maxtime
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple way to approach this is using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.`uid`, s.`activity`, u.`fname`, u.`lname`,
       (SELECT MAX(tt.time)
        FROM timetable tt
        WHERE tt.uid = u.id
       ) as maxtime
FROM `shift` s JOIN
     `users` u
     ON  s.`uid` = u.`id`;
```

The advantage of this approach is performance.  With an index on `timetable(uid, time)`, this should work better than doing an aggregation at the outer level (because the query will take advantage of the index).